# Accessing an ArrayList of another class

Tags: java, arraylist

Ok guys, this may've been posted and asked before, but it's so hard to explain in just a few words, so it's hard as hell to search for it as well!

What I want to do is this, this is my **first** class:

```
public class Footballer {
    int goals;
    String surname= "";
    String team="";
    private static int counter=0;
    private int dres;
}
```

(this is just the header of the class, just to give you the idea of how it looks)...

And this is my **second** class, which contains an ArrayList of the first class:

```
public class FootballTeam{
     String teamname="";
     String league="";
     ArrayList<Footballer>  f;
}
```

And this is my **third** class which contains an ArrayList of the second clas:

```
public class FootballLeague{
     String leaguename="";
     ArrayList<FootballTeam> ft;
}
```

What I want to do is, know how many of footballers are there in the league? Meaning how many of "f"s are in the "ft"... I remember from C++ it was easy, you just did it something like this: ft.f[i]; (where i is a position), then you'd go through each of them, if you wanted to do something with them, or just ask for it's length, if you needed to know how much footballers are there.

I really hope I am clear enough, please ask me if you don't get what I'm asking..

Comment: @CalebBrinkman No, he wants to count the elements, not only access them

Comment: you have to access them before you can call `.size();` that isn't enough to disqualify a dupe; one problem at a time.

Answer (score 1):

It's also easy in Java,

```
int counter = 0;
for(FootballTeam team : ft)
    counter += team.f.size();
```

Comment: I'm getting this: http://prntscr.com/4x4uwg

            `int counter=0;
            for(FootballTeam ff : ft) {
                counter+=ff.f.size();
            }`

Comment: I just tried adding a method to the 2nd class that returns the size() of the ArrayList which it containts (the ArrayList of the 1st class)...

Comment: @BackY make sure f in class FootballTeam is public.

Comment: I tried that too mate..

here are my classes, can someone please check them just in case I've done something wrong :/

`1st class: http://pastebin.com/ed86cYEa 
2nd class: http://pastebin.com/H0DpWcWC 
3rd class: http://pastebin.com/XF9YTeA1`